# Prevent divs from wrapping when parent is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I stop the divs inside of this parent div from wrapping instead of just being cut off?

Code:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
    cont1 = document.getElementById("container1"),
    cont2 = document.getElementById("container2");

slider.addEventListener("input", function() {
    cont1.style.width = slider.value + "px";
    cont2.style.width = slider.value + "px";
}, false);
```

```css
#item {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;  
  float: left;
}

.container {
   height: 100px; 
   background-color: #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<p>use slider to change width of the container</p>
<input id="slider" type="range" max="500">
<p>overflow: hidden</p>
<div class="container" id="container1" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>

<p>overflow: visible</p>
<div class="container" id="container2" style="width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
  <div id="item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8htL5or/44/)

As you can see, as I change the size of the parent div, the divs inside wrap. After searching, I found two solutions. One of them required a set width for the container, by using absolute positioned divs. The other used `white-space: none`,  but no luck.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing the issue on? On Chrome, for me, your overflow:hidden solution does not wrap and may be behaving as you intended.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: @ErikHermansen It still disappears when the width is too small

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of float consider `inline-block` and you will be able to use the `with-space` trick:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
  cont1 = document.getElementById("container1"),
  cont2 = document.getElementById("container2");

slider.addEventListener("input", function() {
  cont1.style.width = slider.value + "px";
  cont2.style.width = slider.value + "px";
}, false);
```

```css
#item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0; /*to avoid white-space between inline-block*/
}
```

```html
<p>use slider to change width of the container</p>
<input id="slider" type="range" max="500">
<p>overflow: hidden</p>
<div class="container" id="container1" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>

<p>overflow: visible</p>
<div class="container" id="container2" style="width: 300px; overflow: visible;">
  <div id="item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your intent correctly, you want the grey slider to 'fade into' the green square, leaving the green square where it is.

For this, you'll want to combine `overflow: hidden` in conjunction with `position: absolute`:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var cont1 = document.getElementById("container1");

slider.addEventListener("input", function() {
  cont1.style.width = slider.value + "px";
}, false);
```

```css
#green {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100px + 8px); /* Red offset + body margin */
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>use slider to change width of the container</p>
<input id="slider" type="range" max="500">
<div class="container" id="container1" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="item" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="green" class="item" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Note that your provided code also has duplicate `#item` IDs, which is invalid markup. I've changed these to classes in my above example.

Comment: The green block seems to be stuck, and does not get cut off when the width is lowered.

Comment: So you want the green block to become smaller when there isn't space to accommodate it?